# Why is a javascript object literal in memory so much bigger than its text file size in JSON form?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a huge JSON (let's call it {...}) which is about 80 MB. All keys/values are strings or objects. I expect that if I load it into javascript by saying var myJson = {...}, the amount of memory it takes up should be not too much bigger than 80 MB. However, using node.js's process.memoryUsage(), I see that as soon as I load this object my memory used increases by about 600 MB. Why does this happen, and what are some workarounds?

Edit: I have changed it from var myJSon = {...} to const myJson = require('./database.json'), with the contents of the json in a .json file rather than a .js file. Strangely, this seemed to reduce the amount of memory used by 50%, so still about 4x as large as the .json file.

Comment: Maybe the file is being compressed and you're seeing the smaller size?

Comment: V8 might be using extra memory for parsing the object.  The actual object size shouldn't be _that_ much larger.  Have you tried using JSON.parse()?

Comment: Are you sure it's not megabits? 600/8 = 75MB

Answer (score 5):

There is a gap between JSON text file size and JSON object memory size.

"the amount of memory it takes up should be not too much bigger than 80 MB" -- That's not true, especially when the object is very big.

According to [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), each string character will occupy 16 bits, and each number value will occupy 64 bits. This means there is a huge gap between JSON text file size and JSON object memory size.

Take the following simple object for example: `{name:'John',age:16}`. Saving this object as a text file only need 20 ascii characters, which means **20 Bytes**. However, store this JSON object in memory needs **at least 30 bytes** ("name".length + "John".length + "age".length = 11, with each character occupy 2 Bytes, it is 22 Bytes; plus the 8 Bytes used for `16`, in all, it needs 30 Bytes.).

The internal object structure ("John" is mapping to "name", and `16` is mapping to "age") also occupy memory. Even without this consideration, the gap between 20 Bytes and 30 Bytes is already big for such a simple object.

The gap would be very big if the JSON object is huge (like the one in question), or if the JSON object structure is very complex.

Of course, JavaScript engine will do some optimization work and reduce the usage of memory. But as ECMAScript specification already stated the bits usage of string and number etc., the gap would alway exist, and such gap is not trivial.

p.s. There is a npm module called [object-sizeof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-sizeof), which can be used to estimate object memory allocation.